# Problem using generic map with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, arguments, wildcard

I have a method that returns a `map` defined as:

```
public Map<String, ?> getData();
```

The actual implementation of this method is not clear to me, but, when I try to do:

```
obj.getData().put("key","value")
```

I get following compile time error message:

> The method put(String, capture#9-of ?)
>   in the type Map
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String, String)

What is the problem? Is `String` not of type anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank you for the answers.. i am impressed of how fast you did react... many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wildcard means "the value type parameter could be anything" - it *doesn't* mean "you can use this as if it were anything you want it to be". In other words, a `Map<String, UUID>` is valid as a `Map<String, ?>` - but you wouldn't want to be able to put a String value into it.

If you want a map which can definitely accept string values, you want:

```
Map<String, ? super String>
```

Comment: String class is final, so just Map<String, String>

Comment: @nybon Suppose you have class A extends Map<String, String> and class B extends Map<String, Object>, you want to write a method that can take either class A or class B as argument. That's when you need Map<String, ? super String>

Answer (score 19):

The return type of

```
Map<String, ?>
```

is the same as

```
Map<String, ? extends Object>
```

The means that the concrete type returned could be a `Map<String, AnyClass>`.  You can't put a `String` into an `AnyClass`, hence the error.

A good general principle is to not use wildcards in method return types.

Answer (score 6):

`Map<String, ?>` is a short form of `Map<String,? extends Object>` and doesn't mean that anything can be added as value. It says that the Map-object can have any generic value type extending `Object`.

This means that the Map object can be a `HashMap<String, String>` or a `HashMap<String, Integer>` as well. Because the compiler can't check which value types will be accepted, he won't let you call methods with the value type as a parameter.

Note:

- You can call methods with the value type as a return value, because everything must extend Object (? extends Object)
- A `Map<String, ? super String>` will have the opposite effect: You can always use a String as parameter, but the return-type is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Map<String, Object> getData();
```

Answer (score -2):

**[EDIT]** This is really wrong... I understood.

My first answer was:

> That's java : String is not an object.
>
> Try with
>
> ```
> obj.getData().put("key",new String("value"));
> ```

But String extends Object... while I thought String was a primitive. I learned something ^^

Comment: A string certainly *is* an object. What precise difference do you believe it would make to call the String constructor explicitly in this case?

Comment: String is not a primitive type, is it?

Comment: No, it's not a primitive type... so why did you claim it's not an object?

Comment: I believed it was a primitive, like a almost object... Mistaken! But what is the difference between my thought and Ben Lings one?

Comment: Ben Lings' answer is *completely* different, and accurate. What do you think the similarity is between your answer and Ben's?

Comment: He told us than Map<?> is the same as List<? extends Object>. And he told than AnyClass, as long as AnyClass extends Object, can't be a String. I did some tries: if I write List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>(), I can't do anything else than list.add(null)... My brain cannot get it...

Comment: OK, it seems I will not have my explanation... I get that List<? extends Object> is a read-only List. I get too that List<? super Object> is the correct answer. But I cannot get why this and that.