# Error while creating generic hash table

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I am getting following error while trying to create generic HashTable.

`The method put(String, capture#2-of ?) in the type Hashtable<String,capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the  arguments (String, int)`

I need a HashTable, something like following:
`HashTable<String, HashTable<String, AnyWrapperType>>`

`by AnyWrapperType i mean it could be Integer or String or Character or Boolean`

I used `?` for `AnyWrapperType`, but i got an error.

I also followed [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921237/problem-using-generic-map-with-wildcard) from where i know what i was doing wrong but could find way out.

```
    Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, String>> paramTocol = new Hashtable<>();

    if (standard != null && (!standard.isEmpty())) {
        Hashtable<String, String> temp = new Hashtable<>();
        temp.put(Appconstants.Col_studentinfo_S_Class,
                AvailableClass.getValueByName(standard));
        paramTocol.put("standard", temp);
    }
    if (section != null && (!section.isEmpty())) {
        Hashtable<String, String> temp = new Hashtable<>();
        temp.put(Appconstants.Col_studentinfo_S_Section, section);

        paramTocol.put("section", temp);
    }
```

Here actual value of `standard is Integer` in database and value corresponding to  `section is char`. I am given all these values as String and i need to store them in HashTable, So i want some raw hashtable that will hold all these values. None of the type is User-defined

Comment: It's not clear what your existing code looks like, or what you're trying to do with the table afterwards (or why you're not using `HashMap`)

Comment: I have added some more description, i hope that will clear my issue

Comment: Not really - we don't know any of the types involved. What's `Appconstants.Col_studentinfo_S_Section` for example?

Comment: `Appconstants.Col_studentinfo_S_Section` is a String which corresponds to column name in database.

Comment: So everything in your sample code is about strings - where do the wrapper types come in? It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* program (a console app) which actually demonstrates your problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the `AnyWrapperType` to `Object`. Since all classes in java are directly or indirectly subclass of Object, so instead of setting a generic type you can set the type to Object. 
When ever you need to get that element you should perform a `type-cast`.

```
HashTable<String, HashTable<String, Object>>
```